# Question about how to flush cache in GCP Memorystore (Redis) DB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, in-memory-database, google-cloud-memorystore

I would like to know if it is possible to execute the redis command below, but in the context of Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Memorystore (which is a Redis compliant inmemory DB):
https://redis.io/commands/flushall

I know that in a normal Redis DB I can flush the cache (anytime I want), but I am not sure I can do the same with GCP MemoryStore DB.

Can anyone give any information about it ?

Thanks!
Jose

Comment: MemoryStore instance and version? Did you try the command? Please post a software problem with error messages. This question is what documentation is for. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Here is a link to commands that are blocked: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/reference/redis-configs#blocked

Answer (score 1):

I followed this tutorial [Connecting to a Redis instance from an App Engine standard environment application](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-standard) and I was able to flush the cache with the command `redis_client.flushdb()` or `redis_client.flushall()`

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    value = redis_client.incr('counter', 10)
    print(value)
    value = redis_client.incr('counter', 10)
    print(value)
    redis_client.flushdb()
    #redis_client.flushall()
    value = redis_client.incr('counter', 10)
    print(value)
    return 'Visitor number: {}'.format(value)
```

Therefore  `flushdb()` and `flushall()` both exist

Comment: Thanks marian.vladoi. Good input. I see you use Python programming language. Do you know if those commands are also available for Java ? thanks!